# AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am making some script, wherein my requirement is to remove some special characters from column names and to make data frame as multi header.
code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
cars = {'day':['aug','aug','sep','sep','aug'],
        'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Hyundai Elite i20'],
        'Type':['sedan,','sedan','hatchback','hatchback','hatchback'],
        'Down Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000,10000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['day','Brand', 'Type','Down Price'])
dfpivot=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['day'],columns=['Brand','Type'],values=['Down Price'],aggfunc=np.max)
dfpivot=pd.DataFrame(dfpivot.to_records())
```

Post this my requirement is to replace "(" & ")" from column name & to split column name with "," to make it multi header
What i tried :

```
dfpivot.columns=dfpivot.columns.str.replace("(","").replace(")","")
dfpivot.columns = dfpivot.columns.str.split(',', expand=True)
```

I am getting the below error, I also tried to check similar questions posted, but it is not helping, will be grateful if someone can help to resolve.

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 10 dfpivot=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['day'],columns=['Brand','Type'],values=['Down Price'],aggfunc=np.max)
> 11 dfpivot=pd.DataFrame(dfpivot.to_records())
> ---> 12 dfpivot.columns=dfpivot.columns.str.replace("(","").replace(")","")
> 13 dfpivot
>
> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all except alpha numerics, white space and comma, split and expand in the columns.

```
dfpivot.columns=dfpivot.columns.str.replace('[^\w\,\s]','',regex=True).str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because the second `replace` is missing its `str` accessor:

```
dfpivot.columns = dfpivot.columns.str.replace("(", "").str.replace(")", "")
#                                                      ^^^
```

However it's simpler to use [`str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for this:

```
dfpivot.columns = dfpivot.columns.str.strip("()").str.split(",", expand=True)

#    day                                                                     'Down Price'
#    NaN    'Audi A4'  'Ford Focus'  'Honda Civic'  'Hyundai Elite i20'  'Toyota Corolla'
#    NaN  'hatchback'   'hatchback'        'sedan'          'hatchback'           'sedan'
# 0  aug          NaN           NaN        22000.0              10000.0           25000.0
# 1  sep      35000.0       27000.0            NaN                  NaN               NaN
```

But note that this will leave single quotes in the column names. If you don't want those quotes, instead use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex:

```
dfpivot.columns = dfpivot.columns.str.replace(r"[()']", "", regex=True).str.split(",", expand=True)

#    day                                                             Down Price                                                            
#    NaN    Audi A4  Ford Focus  Honda Civic  Hyundai Elite i20  Toyota Corolla
#    NaN  hatchback   hatchback        sedan          hatchback           sedan
# 0  aug        NaN         NaN      22000.0            10000.0         25000.0
# 1  sep    35000.0     27000.0          NaN                NaN             NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and such a detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `replace` returns an `Index`, so you need to use another `str` on it:

```
dfpivot.columns=dfpivot.columns.str.replace("(","").str.replace(")","")
```